# CentOS 5: How to resolve php53 RPM dependency conflict with php-foo and php-common?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, php53, php-mcrypt

We are running a CentOS 5.6 system, and want to install php53 with php-mcrypt.

However, this introduces a dependency conflict between php-common & php53-common. Does anyone have a good workaround for this problem?

```
host # yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Processing Dependency: php >= 5.1.6 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is apparently a known problem (See [php-devel](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/php-devel/2011-May/000160.html), [Bug 700179](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700179) and [Bug 695708](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695708)) and this post at the [CentOS forums](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=30881&forum=38&post_id=130891##18), but there is no official fix yet.

Answer (score 5):

Work-around: Use iuscommunity ( http://iuscommunity.org/ ) and install php53u-mcrypt.

In general, you will install packages with named of the form php53u-foo.

Comment: We're going with this workaround for now, but I am hoping to use the RHEL/CentOS packages for simplicity. I am hoping that someone else has come up with a clean solution for this, because this problem affects many php-* packages.

Answer (score 3):

IT is very late but as I came via a search other people might find the following helpful. Had the same trouble described above. Problem was that I tried to run

```
yum install php-gd
```

this threw the error above

```
yum install php53-gd
```

did not as this belongs to installed php package's  installed.

you could find all available packages via

```
yum search php53
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

safer to uninstall php and all php-xxx package before installing php53

Comment: Are you saying that if I install php-xxx first, before installing php53 (this is the reverse of how we did it at first), then the conflict will be avoided?

Comment: Actually  I am using IUS too, sorry for not mentioning earlier.
Anyway, I cleaned up all installed php-xxx package before installing any php53u-xxx and it worked just fined.