# Error while installing php-xml on CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos5, php5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CentOS 5.6: How to resolve php53 RPM dependency conflict with php-mcrypt and php-common?](https://serverfault.com/questions/276459/centos-5-6-how-to-resolve-php53-rpm-dependency-conflict-with-php-mcrypt-and-php)

I am trying to use the PHP DOMDocument Class, which requires the installation of `php-xml` (I'm running CentOS 5.5).

However, upon running `yum install php-xml` I recieve the error 'php53-common conflicts with php-common', so the install fails. I have no idea where to go with this, so any tips are apprciated. Thanks.

Comment: `yum repolist`?

Comment: Do you know which version of PHP you're running/have installed?  Is it possible that you're trying to install a newer version of php-xml and that's trying to install a newer version of the common files?

Comment: @quanta - Apologies, I didn't see that one.

Comment: @JohnK - Running PHP 5.3.3, so the issue was indeed that I was trying to install the wrong version of `php-xml`. `yum install php53-xml` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because I am using PHP 5.3.3, and the install requires you to specify that (I thought it picked up your version and installed the relevent module, but I' obviously wrong).

To fix this problem, `yum install php53-xml` did the trick.

Don't forget to `restart service httpd` after the install.