# CentOS release 6.3 (Final) php-mcrypt Install Fails

Tags: centos6, php-mcrypt

I got a clean installation of `CentOS 6.3`, with `php 5.3.18`.
I tried installing the `epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm` and `epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm` in order to run

`# yum install php-mcrypt`

However it cannot find the package. Also tried

`# yum install php53-mcrypt`

but no luck.

Can Anyone point me on the right direction?

Comment: And where did you get php-5.3.18?

Comment: Could you please post the exact error you are getting after yum command ?

Comment: Can you post the exact error outputs?

Comment: What is the output of `yum repolist`? If EPEL is not listed, it's either disabled in configuration or `epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm` did not install correctly.  (Or, it's not reachable on the network.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CentOS 5.6: How to resolve php53 RPM dependency conflict with php-mcrypt](http://serverfault.com/questions/276459/centos-5-6-how-to-resolve-php53-rpm-dependency-conflict-with-php-mcrypt-and-php)

Answer (score 1):

Install the EPEL REPO via:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

#OR .../x86_64/... for 64bit
```

then you can

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

(EPEL FAQ: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F )