# Resolving "php54w-common-5.4.24-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0"

Tags: centos, php, mcrypt

We're running CentOS release 6.5 and PHP 5.4.24, and I'm trying to get mcrypt-php installed.

When I follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos6, however, the process errors out.

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php54w-common-5.4.24-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I get the feeling I need to [upgrade/uninstall/reinstall PHP](https://serverfault.com/questions/276459/centos-5-how-to-resolve-php53-rpm-dependency-conflict-with-php-foo-and-php-comm), but I've only found instructions on how to do this for php53 and I don't want to risk taking the server offline.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a 3rd-party repo to provide PHP 5.4, and the package php54w-common from that repo is conflicting with php-mcrypt (which is presumably coming from epel), which is expecting the default CentOS 6 version of php-common.

Your 3rd-party PHP provider might provide their own version of mcrypt (try `yum info php54w-mcrypt` and see if that gives you anything).  Otherwise, you're out of luck and you'll need to:

1. Find another package of PHP mcrypt compatible with php54w-common
2. Revert to the CentOS-supported PHP 5.3 instead of using PHP 5.4
3. Build your own PHP 5.4 mcrypt package against the ones from your 3rd-party provider

Good luck!